# Getting Attached Behavior To Work

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to learn about "Attached Behaviors" and have run into a bit of a problem.  The article I'm currently using is:  http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/

In a nutshell I would like to be able to "click" on an entry in a TreeView and have this bring up a file in Notepad.  I have this code to bring up a file in Notepad working via a Command Button in WPF.  For now let's call this command button...Testing.  Here's the XAML I'm using to bind this button to the View.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}">
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Event" Value="MouseDoubleClick"/>
      <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Action" Value="{Binding Path=TestIng}"/>
      <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="ShowThis" />
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

When I double-click on an entry in the TreeView it does indeed execute the code: "TestIng", but it bombs on the following line:

strategy.Execute(CommandParameter)

The actual error is:

Object reference not set to an intance of an object

so this tells me that I have perhaps not set up the "CommandParameter" properly.

Here's the Model with the definition of the "TestIng" Command Button.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using BusinessLib;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TreeViewWithViewModelDemo.LoadOnDemand
{
    public class PublicationsViewModel
    {
        readonly ReadOnlyCollection<CourseViewModel> _courses;
        readonly ICommand _searchCommand;

        public PublicationsViewModel(Course[] courses)
        {
            _courses = new ReadOnlyCollection<CourseViewModel>(
                (from course in courses
                 select new CourseViewModel(course))
                .ToList());
            _searchCommand = new TestIng(this);
        }

        public ReadOnlyCollection<CourseViewModel> Courses
        {
            get { return _courses; }
        }

        public ICommand SearchCommand
        {
            get { return _searchCommand; }
        }
    }

    class TestIng : ICommand
    {
        public TestIng(PublicationsViewModel param1)
        {
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { }
            remove { }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Into This Here");
        }

        public void ShowThis()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Into This Here Number2");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that it is not probably going to be a matter of you giving me the exact answer given the fact I'm only giving you part of the code, but I wonder if you wouldn't mind giving me some ideas on how to proceed and what I might try next.

I think the error is in how I'm defining the CommandParameter in the XAML.  I'm really not sure if I understand how this works, but I think this is the method in the class that you want to have executed when the "MouseDoubleClick" is pressed.  I have two methods in the ViewModel:

```
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        public void ShowThis()
```

Which I am using for simple testing...but these messagebox.show lines don't get executed.  Like I said, I'm getting an error...

Can someone provide me with some insight in how I should define:

```
      <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="ShowThis" />
```

Or what I could possibly look into in order to proceed.  I'm stuck...

Thanks

Comment: If you get an exception on that line you mentioned the `strategy` has to be `null`, the parameter being null would only have consequences inside the execute method.

Answer (score 0):

Change your command binding to point to `SearchCommand` instead of `TestIng`

Your sample code shows `TestIng` as a class, not a property, and you need to bind to the property